# Joining two dataframes only when both start times and end times of one data frame fall into intervals of the other dataframe

Tags: r, left-join, intervals

I want to do an exact join of two temporally aligned dataframes using `interval_left_join`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Utterance = c("(5.127)", ">like how old 's your mom¿ ", 
                                "(0.855)", "eh six:ty:::-one= ", "(0.101)", "(0.166)", "=NOW ", 
                                "(0.622)", "!how! this always plays out  ", "(0.726)", "[when was] that¿= ", 
                                "[yes] ", "(0.163)", "=!this! was on °Wednesday° ", "(0.273)", 
                                "oka[y] "), Starttime_ms = c(0, 5127, 6830, 7685, 9889, 176800, 
                                                             176966, 177372, 177994, 179328, 180054, 180135, 180668, 180831, 
                                                             181720, 181993), Endtime_ms = c(5127, 6830, 7685, 9889, 9990, 
                                                                                             176966, 177372, 177994, 179328, 180054, 180668, 180555, 180831, 
                                                                                             181720, 181993, 182398)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(Q_segment = c(">like I don 't understand< ", "sorry like how old 's your mom¿", 
                                    "[when was] that¿=", "=[did she let you in?]", "=holy [sh:]i:[:t", 
                                    "does it happen] often? ", "[like] ", "[what] type of:: tours is it ", 
                                    "is it [(like a long] ti:me¿", "[or]"), Starttime_ms = c(5127, 
                                                                                             5963, 180054, 253226, 345450, 347454, 348459, 478500, 480669, 
                                                                                             481763), Endtime_ms = c(5963, 6830, 180668, 254156, 347454, 348459, 
                                                                                                                     348724, 480669, 481763, 482000)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Joining these two ata frames produces **more** joins than is desired presumably because `interval_left_join` joins when **either one** of `Starttime_ms` and `Endtime_ms` of `df2` is identical with the first millisecond of `Endtime_ms` or `Starttime_ms` of `df2`:

```
# install package "IRanges":
# if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#   install.packages("BiocManager")
# 
# BiocManager::install("IRanges")
library(BiocManager)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(data.table)

interval_left_join(x = df1,
                   y = df2,
                   by = c("Starttime_ms", "Endtime_ms"))
# A tibble: 17 × 6
   Utterance                       Starttime_ms.x Endtime_ms.x Q_segment            Starttime_ms.y Endtime_ms.y
   <chr>                                    <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>                         <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 "(5.127)"                                    0         5127 >like                          5127         5963
 2 ">like how old 's your mom¿ "             5127         6830 >like                          5127         5963
 3 ">like how old 's your mom¿ "             5127         6830 how old 's your mom¿           5963         6830
 4 "(0.855)"                                 6830         7685 how old 's your mom¿           5963         6830
 5 "eh six:ty:::-one= "                      7685         9889 NA                               NA           NA
 6 "(0.101)"                                 9889         9990 NA                               NA           NA
 7 "(0.166)"                               176800       176966 NA                               NA           NA
 8 "=NOW "                                 176966       177372 NA                               NA           NA
 9 "(0.622)"                               177372       177994 NA                               NA           NA
10 "!how! this always plays out  "         177994       179328 NA                               NA           NA
11 "(0.726)"                               179328       180054 [when was] that¿=            180054       180668
12 "[when was] that¿= "                    180054       180668 [when was] that¿=            180054       180668
13 "[yes] "                                180135       180555 [when was] that¿=            180054       180668
14 "(0.163)"                               180668       180831 [when was] that¿=            180054       180668
15 "=!this! was on °Wednesday° "           180831       181720 NA                               NA           NA
16 "(0.273)"                               181720       181993 NA                               NA           NA
17 "oka[y] "                               181993       182398 NA                               NA           NA
```

How can I join the two data frames more precisely such that **both** `Starttime_ms` **and** `Endtime_ms` of `df2` fall into the respective time intervals of `df1`?

The **desired result** is this:

```
   Utterance                       Starttime_ms.x Endtime_ms.x Q_segment            Starttime_ms.y Endtime_ms.y
   <chr>                                    <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>                         <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 "(5.127)"                                    0         5127 NA                               NA           NA
 2 ">like how old 's your mom¿ "             5127         6830 >like                          5127         5963
 3 ">like how old 's your mom¿ "             5127         6830 how old 's your mom¿           5963         6830
 4 "(0.855)"                                 6830         7685 NA                               NA           NA
 5 "eh six:ty:::-one= "                      7685         9889 NA                               NA           NA
 6 "(0.101)"                                 9889         9990 NA                               NA           NA
 7 "(0.166)"                               176800       176966 NA                               NA           NA
 8 "=NOW "                                 176966       177372 NA                               NA           NA
 9 "(0.622)"                               177372       177994 NA                               NA           NA
10 "!how! this always plays out  "         177994       179328 NA                               NA           NA
11 "(0.726)"                               179328       180054 NA                               NA           NA
12 "[when was] that¿= "                    180054       180668 [when was] that¿=            180054       180668
13 "[yes] "                                180135       180555 NA                               NA           NA
14 "(0.163)"                               180668       180831 NA                               NA           NA
15 "=!this! was on °Wednesday° "           180831       181720 NA                               NA           NA
16 "(0.273)"                               181720       181993 NA                               NA           NA
17 "oka[y] "                               181993       182398 NA                               NA           NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand your desired result, but have you tried `dplyr::join_by()`?  It gives you much more control over your join.

```r
df1 |> 
  dplyr::left_join(
    df2,
    dplyr::join_by(
      y$Starttime_ms >= x$Starttime_ms,
      y$Endtime_ms <= x$Endtime_ms
    )
  ) |>
  dplyr::select(1:4) # remove duplicate columns

#> # A tibble: 17 x 4
#>    Utterance                       Starttime_ms.x Endtime_ms.x Q_segment        
#>    <chr>                                    <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>            
#>  1 "(5.127)"                                    0         5127  <NA>            
#>  2 ">like how old 's your mom¿ "             5127         6830 ">like I don 't ~
#>  3 ">like how old 's your mom¿ "             5127         6830 "sorry like how ~
#>  4 "(0.855)"                                 6830         7685  <NA>            
#>  5 "eh six:ty:::-one= "                      7685         9889  <NA>            
#>  6 "(0.101)"                                 9889         9990  <NA>            
#>  7 "(0.166)"                               176800       176966  <NA>            
#>  8 "=NOW "                                 176966       177372  <NA>            
#>  9 "(0.622)"                               177372       177994  <NA>            
#> 10 "!how! this always plays out  "         177994       179328  <NA>            
#> 11 "(0.726)"                               179328       180054  <NA>            
#> 12 "[when was] that¿= "                    180054       180668 "[when was] that~
#> 13 "[yes] "                                180135       180555  <NA>            
#> 14 "(0.163)"                               180668       180831  <NA>            
#> 15 "=!this! was on °Wednesday° "           180831       181720  <NA>            
#> 16 "(0.273)"                               181720       181993  <NA>            
#> 17 "oka[y] "                               181993       182398  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also for spotting the mistake in the desired output (which I've corrected).

Comment: I get this error: `Error: 'join_by' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'`- does this mean my `dplyr` version or my `R` is too old?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, It sounds like your `dplyr` version is too old.  `join_by()` is from `dplyr` version 1.1.0.  You can refer to this blog post for more info:  https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/01/dplyr-1-1-0-joins/.